# Section Horizontal Lines - Change Color

Tags: sectioning, color, line-spacing, line

how can i change color of section horizontal lines without change header color?
[image]

Code can be find  [here](https://pt.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv)

PS - Im new on latex

Comment: Please post your MWE...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal, but compilable code example (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Here some more informations, which could help to create a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: The code you've posted is unfortunately no MWE. Please add a minimal document with the required packages.

Comment: the code is not made by me, for that, i've some difficulties to find the line where the author defines section line color.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
```

to

```
\colorlet{titlerulecolor}{orange}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[{\color{titlerulecolor}\titlerule}]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{titlerulecolor}{orange}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[{\color{titlerulecolor}\titlerule}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\section{Personal Data}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can choose another color than orange.

Example for an `rgb` color:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{titlerulecolor}{rgb}{.9,.1,.9}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[{\color{titlerulecolor}\titlerule}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\section{Personal Data}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one more thing, how can i put rgb colors instead standard color like "blue" or "green"?

Comment: Example: `\definecolor{titlerulecolor}{rgb}{.9,.1,.9}`, see my updated answer.